# the apparent exception was readily seen to be charmingly and ineffectually disguising her true womanhood

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand the part in italic. I'd appreciate some clarification on this.

When
Lewes turns, in a rather whimsical way, to specific writers,
he can only discern the combinations of Sentiment and Observation
that he has already decided are feminine traits: the signs of gentility, domesticity, and breeding that the title of his article implies. For Lewes, as for other Victorian critics, women of genius did not require a modification in sexual theory; *the apparent exception was readily seen to be charmingly and ineffectually disguising her true womanhood*.

Link to the original text:
https://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/womens-literature-19th-century-british-women-writers

Comment: Victorian (male) critics thought that women's nature made them unsuited to being great writers. According to G.H Lewes, acknowledged geniuses such as Charlotte Bronte and George Sand, who used masculine pseudonyms, did not succeed in disguising their feminine qualities.

Comment: @Kate Bunting - This seems like an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 4):

I think the key words are "charmingly" and "ineffectually." This suggests a very patronizing attitude toward women of genius: that is to say, perhaps, how *adorable* it is that these women are *trying* to behave like men.
That's how I would interpret it, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In Victorian times, attitudes to British women were oppressively and distortingly stereotypical:

> During the reign of Queen Victoria, a woman's place was in the home, as domesticity and motherhood were considered by society at large to be a sufficient emotional fulfilment for females. These constructs kept women far away from the public sphere in most ways
>
> [bbc history](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/trail/victorian_britain/women_home/ideals_womanhood_01.shtml)

To maintain such attitudes in the face of the reality that some women could write, paint, be scientists, organise, run businesses and all other activities of intellectual competence, some men (and indeed, some women) erected fallacious conceptual frameworks of belief that reinforced the domestic stereotype by only acknowledging these other abilities as mere decoration on the central and definitive fixed idea of domestic womanhood. Thus Lewes, while admitting to the genius of a woman in respect of literature, sidelines it as a merely delightful diversion and unsuccessful cover for her true nature (as already immutably defined by Lewes). Essentially, these foolish men defined a woman of ability or genius in their own stereotypical terms and then dismissed any evidence to the contrary by placing it in a separate part of their minds.

Comment: Kind of you to say so. Although it was an almost inevitable consequence of biological function before times of wider affluence and birth control, the assumption that women could or should do no more than domestic things was a great folly.